# How do I use colorbox to make the a black box header with white text with different alignment

Tags: header-footer, tcolorbox

So I'm trying to make a black box header like that of below:

http://hkimr.org/uploads/publication/433/wp-no-27_2015.pdf

I can't figure out how the text can be also left adjust for one phrase and another that is right adjust on the same line in the header box.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} % % No headers, just page numbers
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\colorbox{black}{%
    \parbox[b][0.55cm][c]{17cm}{%
      \centering
      \textcolor{white}{\bfseries\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\small Hong Kong Institute for Monetary Research Working Paper No.02/2016}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\hfill` like this

```
Right aligned text \hfill Left aligned text
```

Comment: wow so elegantly done